# Automatically assign a custom post to a custom taxonomy based on custom field value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, functions

We have a custom post type called `listings`, and each `listing` has a custom field `zipcode` (which is a 5 digit number). We then have a custom taxonomy `area`, which can be "New York", "Los Angeles" etc.

If the `zipcode` is "10001", "10002" or "10003" then it should be assigned to "New York", and if it's "90001" or "90101" then it should be assigned to "Los Angeles" and so on.

How can we automatically assign each `listing` to an `area` based on the `zipcode` value?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this not best answer, however you may try like this

```
add_action('save_post', 'add_my_taxonomy');
function add_my_taxonomy($post_ID) {
    $area = array(
    'ny' => 'New York',
    'la' => 'Los Angeles'
    );
    $zip = array(
    'ny' => '10001, 10002, 10003, 10004, 10005, 10006, 10007, 10008, 10009, 10010, 10011, 10012, 10013, 10014, 10015, 10016, 10017, 10018, 10019, 10020, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024, 10025, 10026, 10027, 10028, 10029, 10030, 10031, 10032, 10033, 10034, 10035, 10036, 10037, 10038, 10039, 10040, 10041, 10043, 10044, 10045, 10046, 10047, 10048, 10055, 10060, 10069, 10072, 10079, 10080, 10081, 10082, 10087, 10090, 10094, 10095, 10096, 10098, 10099, 10101, 10102, 10103, 10104, 10105, 10106, 10107, 10108, 10109, 10110, 10111, 10112, 10113, 10114, 10115, 10116, 10117, 10118, 10119, 10120, 10121, 10122, 10123, 10124, 10125, 10126, 10128, 10129, 10130, 10131, 10132, 10133, 10138, 10149, 10150, 10151, 10152, 10153, 10154, 10155, 10156, 10157, 10158, 10159, 10160, 10161, 10162, 10163, 10164, 10165, 10166, 10167, 10168, 10169, 10170, 10171, 10172, 10173, 10174, 10175, 10176, 10177, 10178, 10179, 10184, 10185, 10196, 10197, 10199, 10203, 10211, 10212, 10213, 10242, 10249, 10256, 10257, 10258, 10259, 10260, 10261, 10265, 10268, 10269, 10270, 10271, 10272, 10273, 10274, 10275, 10276, 10277, 10278, 10279, 10280, 10281, 10282, 10285, 10286, 10292',
    'la' => '90001, 90002, 90003, 90004, 90005, 90006, 90007, 90008, 90009, 90010, 90011, 90012, 90013, 90014, 90015, 90016, 90017, 90018, 90019, 90020, 90021, 90022, 90023, 90024, 90025, 90026, 90027, 90028, 90029, 90030, 90031, 90032, 90033, 90034, 90035, 90036, 90037, 90038, 90039, 90040, 90041, 90042, 90043, 90044, 90045, 90046, 90047, 90048, 90049, 90050, 90051, 90052, 90053, 90054, 90055, 90056, 90057, 90058, 90059, 90060, 90061, 90062, 90063, 90064, 90065, 90066, 90067, 90068, 90070, 90071, 90072, 90073, 90074, 90075, 90076, 90077, 90078, 90079, 90080, 90081, 90082, 90083, 90084, 90086, 90087, 90088, 90089, 90091, 90093, 90094, 90095, 90096, 90097, 90099, 90101, 90102, 90103, 90174, 90185'
    );
    foreach ($zip as $code => $zipcodes){
        $zipcode = explode(',', $zipcodes);
        $customField = get_post_meta($post_ID,'zipcode',true);
        if (in_array($customField,$zipcode)){
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, $area[$code], 'area' );
        }
    }
}
```

## I got those zipcodes list from here

http://www.city-data.com/zipmaps/New-York-New-York.html

http://www.city-data.com/zipmaps/Los-Angeles-California.html

Comment: modified as OP requirement

Answer (score 3):

Modify [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39700/how-to-add-terms-to-a-post-depending-on-its-title/54071#54071) to use the meta field instead of the title. Anything else should be the same.

Comment: Wow fantastic! It's now working from the `post_title` but I can't get it working from the `zip`.

I've added `$customField = get_post_meta($post->ID,'zip',true);` to the beginning, and replaced all `post_title` instances with `$customField`.

When I update the post it says `Cannot access empty property`. Any idea how to use the custom field here?

Thanks!

Comment: Any idea where I'm going wrong with `$customField = get_post_meta($post->ID,'zip',true);` ? Thanks!

Comment: `var_dump( get_post_custom( $post->ID ) );` to see if there is a value.

Comment: toscho, you've been so helpful in this. I really appreciate it, thank you! 

Unfortunately I'm not sure where exactly to use `var_dump` here.. For reference, here's the plugin as it stands now (which isn't working yet, but when `$zip` was `post_title` it worked perfectly from the title - I just need to replace the title with my custom field): http://pastebin.com/Fhsi9gfx . Any thoughts would be very helpful!

Comment: I've used `var_dump` in the template, and it's shown a value for the custom field: `["zip"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10001"` .

Comment: Also, I get the correct value echoed if I use this on the page: `<?php echo (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'zip', true)) ?>`. I just can't get the value to work properly as a variable in the function.