# Assign a custom post to a custom taxonomy based on custom field value

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56031/automatically-assign-a-custom-post-to-a-custom-taxonomy-based-on-custom-field-va/97039#97039) does exactly what I needed to do, but the only thing is I need it to select more than just one category.

So I have changed the code to work based on salary so salary gets entered into a custom field, then it automatically selects the salary banding category which works fine, but now I have a *salary from* and a *salary to* custom field so I have a value of salary to, so how can I get the code to add the post to mulitiple categories based on both values if that makes any sense?

Below is my code that works for the category selection based on the value of salaryband, so I need it to also select the category based on salaryband2 (custom field)

```
function add_my_taxonomy($post_ID) {
    $salary = array(
'1015' => '10 - 15 ph',
'100140' => '100K - 140K',
'101120' => '101K - 120K pa',
'121150' => '121K – 150K pa',
'151170' => '151K – 170K pa',
'171200' => '171K – 200K pa',
'2025' => '20 – 25 ph',
'2025k' => '20K – 25K pa',
'2630' => '26 – 30 ph',
'2630k' => '26K – 30K pa',
'3040' => '30 – 40 ph',
'3140k' => '31K – 40K pa',
'4150' => '41K – 50K pa',
'5160' => '51K – 60K pa',
'6170' => '61K – 70K pa',
'7180' => '71K – 80K pa',
'8190' => '81K – 90K pa',
'91100' => '91K – 100K pa'
    );
    $zip = array(
'1015' => '10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,',
'100140' => '101000, 102000, 103000, 104000, 105000, 106000, 107000, 108000, 109000, 110000, 111000, 112000, 113000, 114000, 115000, 116000, 117000, 118000, 119000, 120000, 121000, 122000, 123000, 124000, 125000, 126000, 127000, 128000, 129000, 130000, 131000, 132000, 133000, 134000, 135000, 136000, 137000, 138000, 139000, 140000,',
'101120' => '101000, 102000, 103000, 104000, 105000, 106000, 107000, 108000, 109000, 110000, 111000, 112000, 113000, 114000, 115000, 116000, 117000, 118000, 119000, 120000,',
'121150' => '121000, 122000, 123000, 124000, 125000, 126000, 127000, 128000, 129000, 130000, 131000, 132000, 133000, 134000, 135000, 136000, 137000, 138000, 139000, 140000, 141000, 142000, 143000, 144000, 145000, 146000, 147000, 148000, 149000, 150000,',
'151170' => '151000, 152000, 153000, 154000, 155000, 156000, 157000, 158000, 159000, 160000, 161000, 162000, 163000, 164000, 165000, 166000, 167000, 168000, 169000, 170000,',
'171200' => '171000, 172000, 173000, 174000, 175000, 176000, 177000, 178000, 179000, 180000, 181000, 182000, 183000, 184000, 185000, 186000, 187000, 188000, 189000, 190000, 191000, 192000, 193000, 194000, 195000, 196000, 197000, 198000, 199000, 200000,',
'2025' => '20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,',
'2630' => '26, 27, 28, 29, 30,',
'2025k' => '20000, 21000, 22000, 23000, 24000, 25000,',
'2630k' => '26000, 27000, 28000, 29000, 30000,',
'3040' => '31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,',
'2630k' => '26000, 27000, 28000, 29000, 30000,',
'3140k' => '31000, 32000, 33000, 34000, 35000, 36000, 37000, 38000, 39000, 40000,',
'4150' => '41000, 42000, 43000, 44000, 45000, 46000, 47000, 48000, 49000, 50000,',
'5160' => '51000, 52000, 53000, 54000, 55000, 56000, 57000, 58000, 59000, 60000,',
'6170' => '61000, 62000, 63000, 64000, 65000, 66000, 67000, 68000, 69000, 70000,',
'7180' => '71000, 72000, 73000, 74000, 75000, 76000, 77000, 78000, 79000, 80000,',
'8190' => '81000, 82000, 83000, 84000, 85000, 86000, 87000, 88000, 89000, 90000,',
'91100' => '91000, 92000, 93000, 94000, 95000, 96000, 97000, 98000, 99000, 100000,'
    );
    foreach ($zip as $code => $salaryband){
        $salaryband = explode(',', $salaryband);
        $customField = get_post_meta($post_ID,'salaryband',true);
        if (in_array($customField,$salaryband)){
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, $salary[$code], 'salary' );
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically assign a custom post to a custom taxonomy based on custom field value](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56031/automatically-assign-a-custom-post-to-a-custom-taxonomy-based-on-custom-field-va)

Comment: Thanks for response ive tried that and it just then overides the orginginal so when i duplicate it slects the salaryband custom field but then selects the salaryband2 custom fireld and just selects that category i want it to select both not just the one if that makes sense thanks

Comment: The question suggested by t3los seems to address the point to me, but I have answered a couple of similar questions lately. Perhaps they will help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91953/minimum-word-count-before-a-post-can-be-made-pending-review/92006#92006 and : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96762/how-to-make-a-meta-box-field-a-requirement/96767#96767

Comment: Let me see if I can figure out what you are asking: You set a single custom meta field called `salary` and you want to set two fields based on that? What are the relationships? Why does your code only try to set one field?

Comment: hi thanks so much for looking at this basically have a custom post type which is vaccancy in that there are a number of taxomony one being salary. within each post there are 2 custom fields salaryband and salaryband2. so what i need it to do is depending on the value of the custom field salary band i need it too add that into the salary category with a band so for examaple say salaryband was 25000 it would automatically be added to the salary category 25k - 30k which my above code does the problem is i want to assign each post to two categories in the salary category list

Comment: (so tick two boxes automatically) the second salary category it should tick is dependant on salaryband2 so eg if salarybandsecond salary category it should tick is dependant on salaryband2 so eg if salaryband2 is 45000 it would be put in the 40k - 50k category so in the one post i need 2 categorys selected based on these 2 cstom field values i can get 1 working but as soon as i add a second it overides it and only selects one category (1tick box) please help thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Hi thanks this is solved now i got help from a developer i know he fixed for me basically wp_set_object_terms() has a fourth argument called append. Setting that to true during the call should add the term without unsetting the already set terms.

so thats if anyone else has this issue thanks again to all that have commented thanks