# Assign tags records that have a keyword

Tags: tags

I have a lot of records without labels, I want to assign a specific tag such records. If the name of the record found a certain word, then it is assigned a specific tag. I think it can be done through SQL-query, but how to realize it is not possible, because the tags and records are in different tables. I would be very grateful for your help.
Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39700/how-to-add-terms-to-a-post-depending-on-its-title)?

Comment: Great idea, but I wanted to change reflected in the database, that is to make SQL-query, but I do not know what.

Comment: That would be a rather complex SQL query. Not sure what the best approach would be for that.

Comment: Clearly, what other options?

Comment: I can't why @toscho's answer won't do the job? There's even a code snippet at the bottom to apply to all *existing* posts. You don't need to manually craft the SQL yourself, let PHP do the work!

Comment: I just do not quite understand how this plugin. I am a beginner in WordPress